# Android web socket set server end point

Tags: java, android, sockets

I would like to use a socket to connect to
    "IPHERE:8080/chat/" with the IPHERE being replaced by a real endpoint IP.
However whenever I use

```
    private static final int SERVERPORT = 8080;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "IPHERE/chat/";
    Socket socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVERPORT);
```

I received the error message :

04-25 22:38:37.745  12521-12959/com.package.slidingtabs W/System.err﹕ java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "IPHERE/chat/": No address associated with hostname

Comment: You're confusing HTTP with TCP.  Sockets have no notion or a URL.

Comment: That would make sense, seems like JavaScript bastardizes this as this "socket" works

Comment: Now you're confusing TCP sockets with Web Sockets.  Web Sockets are built on top of HTTP; browser Javascript cannot create raw sockets.